# Can't delete OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I created some time ago for one project an [OAuth consent screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) on Google API & Credential
This is very stupid but it seems there is no way to delete it once created.
Anyone has any clue on how to delete it without the need to detele the whole project?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you need to delete it? Have you deleted all the credentials using Oauth2?

Comment: Yes I deleted it, because I don't use it and I don't want someone possibly connect to the app via oauth, even if it is in a test stage I would like to come back to the original state

Comment: No one can connect to it if you dont have an app using an oauth2 token.

Answer (score 17):

Currently there is no way to delete the consent screen once you have created it.  I suggest that you send feedback to the team and let them know they should offer this option.

Top left corer click the question mark and send feedback.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer (and is still a problem in 2022). I thought for a minute I was going nuts not being able to find the 'delete' option.

Comment: I need to bring this up with the team again, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Still there is no option to delete :(

Comment: its easy enough to just create a new project 

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Any update on this? I added one and can't delete it

Comment: Yes I do actually Google says to create a new project